# Anomalous iptables entry with fail2ban (is it misconfigured to block outward traffic?)

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

Overall we are very satisfied with fail2ban as it has accumulated several dozen neverdowell IP addresses in our iptables rules.

However I notice the following rule has also appeared:

```
Chain fail2ban-apache-overflows (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  <our-server-hostname>               anywhere
```

I'm not very good at reading iptables rules, but my interpretation of that rule is that it blocks all outward traffic. Is that correct? Why would it appear in our iptables ruleset? (Outbound traffic does not actually appear to be blocked.)